# How to turn parenthesis notation for tree into actual tree drawing?

Tags: notation, trees

$( (A) B (C) ) D (E)$. I have this notation and I have to turn it into a tree drawing. But I can't figure out what's going on, since the $A$ between parenthesis does not make sense to me.

Comment: not really. what I don't understand is why the A node is alone in the parenthesis and that doesn't happen in any of the examples i've seen here. 
For me, the A should be the father node of the tree, but it doesn't have any children according to this notation.

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't a pair of parentheses enclosing the entire expression.  Do you have any reference for the notation?

Comment: According to @gt6989b 's notation, I guess, it would be $(D\, (B\, A\, C)\, E)$.

Comment: intuitively I would interpret this notation as every time you go inside a pair of parenthesis you do down in the tree. Under this interpretation the top node of the tree is D, with a left children B and a right children E, and B have two children also: A in the left and C in the right